# Fill the NAs values in a dataframe based on calculation of columns in other dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble, coalescing

I have 2 dataframes. The `RP` and the `RP2`. My goal is to fill the `NAs` of `RP` columns `Country_1` and `Country_2` based on the conditions below:

1.If a cell of `RP` has already value leave it as it is.

2.If it has `NA` then see the `TreatmenArea` and `Subarea` of that cell and find the same pair of `TreatmenArea`, `Subarea` in `RP2` then:

a.multiply this value with the `PFaverage` column of `RP2` and divide by 100.

b.if the relative cell in `RP2` is `NA` as well then leave the value in `RP` as `NA`

```
RP<-structure(list(ProductFamily = c("PF_1", "PF_10", "PF_10", "PF_100", 
"PF_100", "PF_101", "PF_102", "PF_102", "PF_102", "PF_102", "PF_103", 
"PF_103", "PF_104", "PF_105", "PF_106", "PF_106", "PF_106", "PF_106", 
"PF_107", "PF_108", "PF_109", "PF_11", "PF_110", "PF_110", "PF_111", 
"PF_111", "PF_111", "PF_112", "PF_112", "PF_113", "PF_113", "PF_113", 
"PF_114", "PF_115", "PF_115", "PF_116", "PF_117", "PF_118", "PF_119", 
"PF_12", "PF_12", "PF_12", "PF_120", "PF_120", "PF_120", "PF_120", 
"PF_120", "PF_120", "PF_121", "PF_122"), TreatmenArea = c("TA_7", 
"TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_6", "TA_6", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", 
"TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", 
"TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_7", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_7", 
"TA_7", "TA_7", "TA_7", "TA_7", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_6", 
"TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_5", "TA_5", 
"TA_5", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_4", 
"TA_4"), Subarea = c("SA_16", "SA_5", "SA_5", "SA_15", "SA_15", 
"SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", 
"SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", 
"SA_17", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_22", "SA_22", "SA_22", "SA_22", 
"SA_22", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_15", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", 
"SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_11", "SA_11", "SA_11", "SA_6", "SA_6", 
"SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_6", "SA_10", "SA_10"), Country_1 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 92.6961421759861, NA, NA, NA, NA, 78.3001808318264,NA, NA, NA, 106.832963501416, 0.613496932515337, 104.21011973735, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 99.5238622522423, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
89.0343347639485, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 101.231684009344, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Country_2 = c(NA, 
NA, 161.55950752394, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 59.1346153846154, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 128.113063407181, 93.3812839543959, NA, NA, NA, 137.724550898204, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 90.1602849510241, 37.3939722071828, NA, NA, 40.9756097560976, 
NA, NA, NA, 87.0095902353967, NA, NA, NA, 50.4591590140164, 92.1639413888299, 
44.7601588756493, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 100.053835800808, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 136.420722135008, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

and the RP2

```
RP2<-structure(list(TreatmenArea = c("TA_1", "TA_1", "TA_1", "TA_1", 
"TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_2", "TA_3", "TA_4", "TA_4", "TA_5", "TA_5", 
"TA_5", "TA_6", "TA_6", "TA_7", "TA_7", "TA_7", "TA_7", "TA_7", 
"TA_7", "TA_7", "TA_7", "TA_8", "TA_9"), Subarea = c("SA_1", 
"SA_2", "SA_3", "SA_4", "SA_5", "SA_6", "SA_7", "SA_8", "SA_10", 
"SA_9", "SA_11", "SA_12", "SA_13", "SA_14", "SA_15", "SA_16", 
"SA_17", "SA_18", "SA_19", "SA_20", "SA_21", "SA_22", "SA_23", 
"SA_24", "SA_25"), Country_1 = c(101.37519256645, 105.268942332558, 
100.49933368058, 104.531597221684, NaN, 83.4404308144341, 86.2833044714836, 
81.808967345926, 79.6786979951661, 77.6863475527052, NaN, 78.3001808318264, 
112.499238782021, 113.526674294436, NaN, 108.350959378962, NaN, 
NaN, 102.243471199266, NaN, 104.323270355678, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
100), Country_2 = c(98.7267717862572, 83.9572019653478, 97.164068306148, 
103.654771613923, 161.55950752394, 75.4091957339533, 96.5255996196344, 
99.8317785594128, 88.1477193135348, NaN, NaN, NaN, 151.411687458963, 
107.652477161141, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 92.4695215620261, NaN, 
88.9890571623243, 39.1847909816402, 87.0642912470953, NaN, NaN
), PFaverage = c(9.09293100169062, 16.2821052631579, 9.76688333333333, 
13.4754047619048, 17.8741666666667, 9.42546567085954, 12.6145188492064, 
12.4536666666667, 7.36169471153846, 13.1581818181818, 21.0866666666667, 
9.58, 16.2525049019608, 11.552822039072, 12.6908333333333, 20.5489611111111, 
11.99, 7.19134920634921, 8.51728472222222, 5.97, 12.2264183501684,6.37925, 16.1375, 11.9384615384615, 15.9185714285714)), class = c("data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -25L))
```

If for example we check first row of `Country_1` in RP we see that its `NA` and its `Subarea` is `SA_16` so we move to `RP2` and check that the relative value for `Country_1` and `Subarea SA_16` is `108.35`. So the calculation is `108.35*20.54(PFaverage)/100`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

RP2 %>% 
  mutate_at(c("Country_1", "Country_2"), 
            list(PFa = ~. * PFaverage / 100)) %>% 
  select(TreatmenArea, Subarea, contains("PFa")) %>% 
  right_join(RP, . , by = c("TreatmenArea" , "Subarea")) %>% 
  mutate(Country_1 = coalesce(Country_1, Country_1_PFa),
         Country_2 = coalesce(Country_2, Country_2_PFa)) %>% 
  select(-contains("PFa")) 

#>    ProductFamily TreatmenArea Subarea   Country_1  Country_2
#> 1           PF_1         TA_7   SA_16  22.2649965        NaN
#> 2          PF_10         TA_2    SA_5         NaN  28.877416
#> 3          PF_10         TA_2    SA_5         NaN 161.559508
#> 4         PF_100         TA_6   SA_15         NaN        NaN
#> 5         PF_100         TA_6   SA_15         NaN        NaN
#> 6         PF_101         TA_2    SA_6  92.6961422   7.107668
#> 7         PF_102         TA_2    SA_6   7.8646492   7.107668
#> 8         PF_102         TA_2    SA_6   7.8646492   7.107668
#> 9         PF_102         TA_2    SA_6   7.8646492  59.134615
#> 10        PF_102         TA_2    SA_6   7.8646492   7.107668
...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: good thought but I see that every calculated value is the same for every column which does not make sense as I explain in my edited example.

Comment: @firmo23 I guess you mean same values for multiple rows, cause I don't see them being the same between the columns. In that case, if you look closer, you see that those rows have the same TreatmentArea and Subarea, so they match with the same row of RP2, hence, returning the same calculated value. Please clarify further.